# Como se recorre un base de datos con jsp

Tags: java, base-de-datos, netbeans, jsp, tomcat

Estoy programando en JSP y un archivo forEach no me trae los datos de una base de datos , Ya tengo las librerias instaladas de JSTL ya puse el taglib como pueden ver y otro error que me pasa es que cuando lo agrego al web.xml me sale error en el apache tomcat , que puede ser?

no me esta entrando en el forEach , no se estan mostrando los datos si lo quito el taglib si se muestran los daatos

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>
```

```
 <c:forEach var="dato" items="${datos}">
            <tr>
               <td>${dato.getId()}</td>
               <td>${dato.getNom()}</td>
               <td>${dato.getCorreo()}</td>
               <td>${dato.getTel()}</td>
               <td>
                   <form>
                        <input type = "submit" value = "Editar">
                        <input type = "submit" value = "Delete">
                   </form>
               </td>
          </tr>
   </c:forEach>
```

Este es mi controlador de java

```
@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String accion = request.getParameter("accion");
        switch(accion){
            case "Listar":
                List<Persona>datos=dao.listar();
                request.setAttribute("datos" , datos);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
                break;
            default:
                throw new AssertionError();
        }
    }
```

Y mi clase PersonaDAO

```
public class PersonaDAO {
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    Conexion c = new Conexion();
    Connection con;
    
    public List listar(){
        List<Persona>lista = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql = "select * from persona";
        try{
            con = c.conectar();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()){
                Persona p = new Persona();
                p.setId(rs.getString(1));
                p.setNom(rs.getString(2));
                p.setCorreo(rs.getString(3));
                p.setTel(rs.getString(4));
                lista.add(p);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
        return lista;
    }
}
```

Esta es mi primera pregunta así que muchas gracias de antemano y cualquier sugerencia de como mejorar el hacer de mis preguntas es bienvenida , Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]. 1. ¿Tiene datos la tabla en la base de datos? 2. ¿Cuál es _el error en el Tomcat_? 3. La etiqueta del IDE (en este caso [netbeans]) no tiene relación con la pregunta. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorarla.

Comment: Si , si tiene datos y no me saale ningun error en apache tomcat , puse la etiqueta de netbeans por que en este IDE lo estoy desarrollando , la borro?

Comment: Lo del error en Tomcat lo mencionaste en tu pregunta...

Comment: Cuando le agrego web.xml  `<taglib-location>/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.7.jar</taglib-location>` me saltaba error en tomcat , la direccion que esta puesta es un ejemplo

Comment: ```org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp (lÃ­nea: [50], columna: [24]) El tgag final "&lt;/c:forEach" estÃ¡ desequilibrado ``` Este error me sale en tomcat

Comment: Por las dudas: ¿acaso con el `<c:forEach>` no debería ir acompañado de `<c:out>`? Hay que revisar la sintaxis...

Comment: ya tambien lo intente como se muestra aca https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332921/jspstuck-in-the-error-unterminated-ltcforeach-tag y nada

Comment: No olvides [edit] tu pregunta para explicar/mostrar lo que ya has intentado. ¿Da otro error al agregar los `<c:out>`?

Comment: Cuando lo pongo no me aparece nada pero analizando el codigo ya creo que encontre el verdadero problema , en PersonaDAO no me entre al while y no se me esta creando la clase persona es el metodo listar

Comment: Ya hize otra pregunta con lo otro

Answer (score 0):

El error lo tenia en la conexion lo tenia asi

```
Class.forName("Oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

y era asi que lo debia de tener

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```